# Как вывести данные в браузер node js, websocket

Tags: node.js, websocket

Мне нужно получать котировки валют в реальном времени, без перезагрузки страницы и нажатий на кнопки.

Для решения этой задачи пришлось прибегнуть к следующим технологиям: node js, websocket.io, Redis, API донора данных.

В консоли получаю вот такие данные:

{"symbol":"EURUSD","bid":1.13624,"ask":1.13624,"price":1.13624}

по сути, все работает, это мне и нужно. Но, я не могу понять, как эти же данные передать в браузер, чтобы было так:

EURUSD | bid - 1.13624 | ask - 1.13624 | price - 1.13624

Вот код js:

```
const redis = require('redis');
const settings = {
    REDIS: {
        HOST: 'localhost'
    }
}
let redisClient = new redis.createClient(settings.REDIS);

function getQuote(symbol, callback) {
    redisClient.get(symbol, (error, quote) => {
        if (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
        quote = JSON.parse(quote);
        callback(quote);
    });
}

setInterval(() => {
    getQuote('EURUSD', (q) => console.log(q));
}, 10);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен следующим кодом JS:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    setInterval(() => {
        getQuote('BTCUSD', (q) => {
            io.emit('get_quote', q);
        });
    }, 10);
});
```

Более детально вопрос рассматривается на [английском Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54265012/data-output-in-real-time-to-the-browser-without-restarting-node-js-websocket/54265353?noredirect=1#comment95364403_54265353)